# AddDbContextPool together with AddInterceptors problem

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have used AddDbContext() method to register my EF DbContext classes using DI. It works well, and I can also add an interceptor like this:

```
        services.AddDbContext<TContextService, TContextImplementation>((provider, opt) =>
        {
            opt.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(enableSensitiveLogging);
            opt.AddInterceptors(provider.GetRequiredService<AzureAdAuthenticationDbConnectionInterceptor>());
        });
```

Note the first parameter in the optionsAction being a provider. This allows me to add an interceptor like above.

However, now I'd like to use the `AddDbContextPool` instead. The `optionsAction` no longer gives me the provider.

```
        services.AddDbContextPool<TContextService, TContextImplementation>(opt =>
        {
            opt.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(enableSensitiveLogging);
            opt.AddInterceptors(???.GetRequiredService<AzureAdAuthenticationDbConnectionInterceptor>());
        });
```

..and at this stage I cannot 'new' up an instance of my interceptor. And I don't want to call `services.BuildServiceProvider()` here either.

So, long story short: how can I achieve the same thing with `AddDbContextPool` as I can with `AddDbContext()`?

I guess I can inject an `IServiceProvider` in some class and do a late resolve, but wanted to check if anyone else has faced this challenge?

Answer (score 3):

The [`AddDbContextPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontextpool) extension method has an overload that passes both an `IServiceProvider` and a `DbContextOptionsBuilder` argument via the `optionsAction`.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddDbContextPool<TContextService,TContextImplementation> (
    this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, 
    Action<IServiceProvider, DbContextOptionsBuilder> optionsAction, 
    int poolSize = 1024
) 
where TContextService : class 
where TContextImplementation : DbContext, TContextService
```

Your code would look like below

```
services.AddDbContextPool<TContextService, TContextImplementation>((serviceProvider, opt) =>
{            
    opt.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(enableSensitiveLogging);
    opt.AddInterceptors(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<AzureAdAuthenticationDbConnectionInterceptor>());
});
```

Comment: Yes of course. I cannot believe I missed that one. Doh! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :-)